# ERROR: pg_repack failed with error: ERROR: column "relhasoids" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pg-repack

I'm using pg_repack extension to perform full vacuum on my database tables. Till now , I was using postgres-11. Now, I have upgraded it to postgres-12.4.
After upgrading when I started doing full vacuum again- I got below error:

```
   ERROR: pg_repack failed with error: ERROR:  column "relhasoids" does not exist
```

Here are in detail:

```
    pg_repack  -U postgres --no-order --no-kill-backend  --table channatest shiwangini

   ERROR: pg_repack failed with error: ERROR:  column "relhasoids" does not exist
   LINE 19:         CASE WHEN relhasoids
                       ^
   QUERY:
   SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(param), ', ')
   FROM (
   -- table storage parameter
   SELECT unnest(reloptions) as param
   FROM pg_
```

How can I avoid this problem in postgres -12 version? I have tried with installing pg_repack12 already and pg_repack version 1.4.5 only installed on my machine which has support for postgres -12. Still the same error.

```
     /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_repack --version

     pg_repack 1.4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL v12 has done away with the `relhasoids` column of the `pg_class` catalog, because the undelying concept does no longer exist in v12.

You should use [version 1.4.5](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack/releases/tag/ver_1.4.5) or better of pg_repack, where support for PostgreSQL v12 was added.

Comment: pg_repack version 1.4.5 only installed on my machine. Still getting the same issue. I'm editing my question with more details

Comment: Then it is not installed properly. I looked at the source, and it replaces `relhasoids` with `false` in v12. Perhaps you ran `configure` with an older version of PosttgreSQL.

Comment: I uninstalled older version of repack and  installed new one using this commad: sudo yum install pg_repack12   ..still same issue :(

Comment: Strange. Perhaps open an issue with the project.

Answer (score 0):

My problem fixed with latest pg_repack release on 30th sept 2020. pg_repack 1.4.6.

Here is what I did:

- Uninstall/Remove all old installation.
- Installed new version of pg_repack. --  sudo  yum install pg_repack12
- Connected to database dropped the existing extension and created a new one.
  drop extension pg_repack ;
  create extension pg_repack ;
- Re-run repack. This time I was able to repack successfully.